# is it possible to save dataframe to atlassian page using api?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, confluence

How to save pandas dataframe directly to Atlassian confluence page using API in python?
I used atlassian-python-api library. but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the altassian python api, you should be able to do this relatively easily

From the [documentation for the confluence module](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html), running the `confluence.create_page` command will create a page in your given workspace.

```
confluence.create_page(space, title, body, parent_id=None, type='page', representation='storage', editor='v2')
```

In your case, if you want to create the pandas dataframe as a table in confluence, you should use the `DataFrmae.to_markdown` command introduced in pandas version 1.0.0.

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html), the command will generate markdown which you can see below.

```
s = pd.Series(["elk", "pig", "dog", "quetzal"], name="animal")
print(s.to_markdown())


|    | animal   |
|---:|:---------|
|  0 | elk      |
|  1 | pig      |
|  2 | dog      |
|  3 | quetzal  |
```

Which will yield markdown as such.

|  | animal |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | elk |
| 1 | pig |
| 2 | dog |
| 3 | quetzal |

In your case, you should attempt to assign the markdown to the body parameter

```
 confluence.create_page(space, title, body=df.to_markdown(), parent_id=None, type='page', representation='storage', editor='v2')
```

Which should yield the result you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Another option as the method provided by [@zhqiat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3254869/zhqiat) would be to convert the dataframe to html.

```
df = pd.Series(["elk", "pig", "dog", "quetzal"], name="animal")

confluence.create_page(
    space, 
    title, 
    body=df.to_html(), 
    parent_id=None, 
    type='page',
    representation='storage', 
    editor='v2',
)
```

In my case `DataFrame.to_markdown()` did not work, it seems that there were issues with the newline characters (\n). But `DataFrame.to_html()` did work.